# How can I set up a command button to ask for input to change the default value of a text box in a form?

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016, ms-access-2003

First, I'd like to say that I am 98% self taught so I'll freely admit that I may be a little dense when it come to some things here.

So here we go. What I am trying to do is to change the default value using a command button, since I am just writing the database and others will be using it. So I am doing my best to idiot-proof the database. Here is the code I am using:

```
Forms!frmMainentry!txtStation.DefaultValue = """?"""
```

Where the ? is, is where I need to be able to change the default value. To give you an idea why, at our facility we have 7 assembly lines, each line has 5 to 8 work stations, each work station has 2 to 15 racks of parts. Most of these were set up to quickly and have been changed and moved around to the point that people have a hard time finding stuff. This database is just meant to be a short term fix until the engineers decide to fix things.

So far, my form works as intended. Once this is working, I can go on to the easy stuff. LOL  Since I have been working on this button for more than 3 days, ANY help you can give will be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Forms!frmMainentry!txtStation.DefaultValue = Chr(34) & Me!InputTextbox.Value & Chr(34)
```

Comment: When I tried this, it changed the value in the control to #NAME? And when I went to a new record, it went back to a blank control. But thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh, _19_ months to get this far! Replace `InputTextbox` with the actual name of your textbox.

Comment: Sorry, 19 months ago we had a change in project leaders and she felt this was unnecessary and I was taken off the project. Last month the "Customer" stepped in and started asking questions. Bottom line, she was removed and we went back to work. So here I am starting all over again.

Comment: Better late than never. Welcome back!

Comment: Thanks, My only problem is that I wasn't able to keep up with what I had already learned and she had the computer I was working with reformatted and I lost everything. I tried to get access to the server, but she denied it so I couldn't even save what I had. Sooo, I'm starting from scratch all over again.